Is the magnetic field in an ideal coaxial cable carrying a TEM wave solely defined by the Ampere/Maxwell displacement current?
If I have a plain TEM wave in an ideal coaxial cable, a simple solution to the wave equation assumes a wave in the source free region between the center conductor and the shield. The magnetic field is calculated only from the changing electric field (displacement current) in the Ampere/Maxwell equation.
Is this a complete description of the magnetic field in the dielectric?
I ask because the magnetic field from this changing electric field has non-zero curl in the dielectric. If I now also consider the electron current in the center conductor, occurring from the boundary condition (PEC), then there is a magnetic field with curl only in the conductor (or where the surface current flows in an ideal cable) and a magnetic field with no curl in the dielectric.
Is the non-curling magnetic field in the dielectric (calculated from the current flow) somehow already accounted for in the magnetic field derived as part of the traveling wave? It seems to me that the TEM wave should completely describe the magnetic and electric fields but I'm not clear on how to account for the magnetic field from the current flow.

I don't understand something in your question: "If I now also consider the electron current in the center conductor... then there is a magnetic field with curl only in the conductor... and a magnetic field with no curl in the dielectric". Can you please elaborate why do you think that's so? In the source-free region, by definition there is no current, but there is displacement current, so there must be a curl to the magnetic field

There is a current in the center conductor (in the z direction), which according to Ampere's law, gives a curling the magnetic field proportional to the current density. There is no electron current in the space between the conductors but there is a non-curling magnetic field that drops as 1/r arising from the current on the wire.

yeah, but you're forgetting the displacement current, which makes the curl of the magnetic field there non-zero

No, I talk about that.

so your question isn't clear because you explicitly say "and a magnetic field with no curl in the dielectric", which is not true

In the third paragraph I say ... "I ask because the magnetic field from this changing electric field has non-zero curl in the dielectric". It is the magnetic field resulting from  from the conduction current that has no curl in the dielectric.

The magnetic field will have a curl in the region, due to the displacement current, as said. You can add the magnetic field from the current in the inner conductor and it won't affect the curl, because curl is linear and just like you said, that contribution has 0 curl. So there is no contradiction

It turns out that there are vacuum (or linear-dielectric bound-charge) solutions to the Maxwell equations for a coaxial cable (c.f. Griffiths chapter 9), and the associated coupled equations aren't terribly difficult to solve in simple cases such as coaxial cables with circular or rectangular cross sections. However, the solutions typically aren't that different from what you would find if you ignored the magnetic field to solve for the electric field first and then calculated the magnetic field 'induced' by the electric field.  The reason for this is essentially that $c$ (the speed of light) is very large by normal standards, even in a typical dielectric, and even for typical electronic signaling applications, and so $\epsilon\mu = 1/c^2$ can be treated as a "small" perturbation.
Solutions with a non-zero $E_z$ component (the component parallel to the wire) are harder to compute as they will tend to induce a nonzero conduction current along the inner and outer layers of the wire.  In principle you would need to solve a coupled system of equations involving constitutive relations for the conductors (which may have a surface charge.)  If $E_z=0$, as is typical away from the ends of the wire, there is no induced current and the signal propagates purely as an electromagnetic wave.

Unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure this helps in answering my question. I see in Griffiths (9.5.3) the relation between E and B of the source free wave but that is not what I'm asking.

Are you asking why the field between the cables is given by one solution of the vacuum/dielectric Maxwell equations and not another?

A wave equation solution results in a B field with curl in the region between the conductors but if I consider the current I get a magnetic field with no curl in the same region. I'm trying to reconcile these two seemingly contradictory results.

You can't have a time dependent $B$ field without an accompanying $E$ field, and a time dependent $E$ field is associated with a "current" in Maxwell's equations.  In vacuum, the time dependence of $E$ and $B$ fields accounts for the nonzero curl.

Yes, but does that include the B field from the conduction current and if so how (since it has a zero curl)?

Solutions with a non-zero $E_z$ component (the component parallel to the wire) are harder to compute as they will tend to induce a nonzero conduction current along the inner and outer layers of the wire.  In principle you would need to solve a coupled system of equations involving constitutive relations for the conductors (which may have a surface charge.)  If $E_z=0$, as is typical away from the ends of the wire, there is no induced current and the signal propagates purely as an electromagnetic wave.

In the case I described, Ez is 0 as we are talking about an ideal coaxial cable (0 resistance in the cable and 0 conductance in the dielectric) and a TEM wave.
A surface current on the conductors will be present on the PEC (center conductor and shield).

To answer my own question  ... I think it comes down to the different direction of the curl of the magnetic fields caused by the conduction current density (μJ) and the displacement current from (-$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$).
The curl of the magnetic field caused by the conduction current density is in the direction of the current (z direction) but the direction of the curl of the magnetic field from the displacement current is in the radial direction (ρ) of the E field.  (The magnetic field lines in both cases are coaxial with the center conductor of course)
(there is a magnetic field with curl in/on the cable but a magnetic field without curl in the dielectric from the conduction current.)
When deriving the integral form of Ampere/Maxwell we use Stokes' theorem and  integrate the curl component normal to the surface, over the surface, to get the line integral of the magnetic around the boundary. If this surface is bounded by the Amperian  loop coaxial with the center conductor, then the curl of the magnetic field caused by the displacement current (which is radial) has zero contribution normal to the surface and thus plays no part in the calculation.  Therefore, although the magnetic field in the dielectric has curl in the radial (ρ) direction, it plays no part the calculation of current in/on the center conductor.
This make intuitive sense when also considering the L/C lumped circuit representation.
